# GWT XMPP client using GWT-Strophe

Tags: gwt, strophe, jsni

I'm using [GWT-Strophe](https://launchpad.net/gwt-strophe) to connect to my XMPP server.  Things are going well and I am able to connect to my XMPP server and send other users messages. I'm having a problem with receiving messages. I'm attempting to copy the Strophe echobot example, but the code in my Handler is not getting executed when a message is received.

Here is the code I am using to connect and register the handler:

```
connection = new Connection("http://localhost/proxy/");
handler = new Handler<Element>() {

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Element element) {
        GWT.log("Handling...");
        GWT.log(element.toString());

        String to = element.getAttribute("to");
        String from = element.getAttribute("from");
        String type = element.getAttribute("type");

        NodeList<com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element> elems = element.getElementsByTagName("body");

        if ((type == null ? "chat" == null : type.equals("chat")) && elems.getLength() > 0) {
            Element body = (Element) elems.getItem(0);

            GWT.log("ECHOBOT: I got a message from " + from + ": " + body.getText());
            String[][] attributes = {{"to", from}, {"from", to}, {"type", "chat"}};    
            Builder reply = Builder.$msg(attributes).cnode(body.copy());    
            connection.send(reply.tree());

            GWT.log("ECHOBOT: I sent " + from + ": " + body.getText());
        }    
        return true;
    }
};

StatusCallback callback = new Connection.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void statusChanged(Status status, String reason) {

        if (status == Status.CONNECTING) {
            GWT.log("Strophe is connecting.");
        } else if (status == Status.CONNFAIL) {
            GWT.log("Strophe failed to connect.");
        } else if (status == Status.DISCONNECTING) {
            GWT.log("Strophe is disconnecting.");
        } else if (status == Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            GWT.log("Strophe is disconnected.");
        } else if (status == Status.CONNECTED) {
            GWT.log("Strophe is connected.");
            connection.addHandler(null, null, "message", null, null, handler);
            Builder pres = Builder.$pres(null);
            connection.send(pres);

            GWT.log("ECHOBOT: Send a message to " + connection.getJid() + " to talk to me.");
        }

    }
};

connection.connect("me@myserver.com", "password", callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
connection.addHandler(null, null, "message", null, null, handler);
```

with

```
connection.addHandler(null, "message", null, null, null, handler);
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post here how you connected gwt-strophe (if you successfully connected)?
Or if you found better solution please post it here. I've made GWT compatible module from gwt-strophe(included gwt.xml and all sources) and used in my GWT project. During compilation there was no error but when i called my widget it says "Cannot read property 'Connection' of undefined". After some code inspection i didn't found where Strophe object is initialized

```
private native JavaScriptObject connection(String boshService) /*-{
    var connection = new $wnd.Strophe.Connection(boshService);
    return connection;
}-*/;
```

Error thrown during runtime execution because window.Strophe object is undefined
p.s. i haven't found here how to add comment so i've made "answer" to ask question in this thread...
All i need is connection from GWT to my openfire server