# GWT - Strophe XMPP client

Tags: gwt, xmpp, strophe

My question is how to configure GWT-Strophe ?
I've already searched many GWT XMPP clients and trying to use gwt-strophe
I've already looked at [GWT XMPP client using GWT-Strophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618434/gwt-xmpp-client-using-gwt-strophe). Problem is window.Strophe is undefined. May be there is something i must include?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to include the native JS lib : `strophe.min.js`
You can do it by adding a JS script into the HTML (head part), for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/strophe.min.js"></script>
```

This line should be before the script line for `...nocache.js`